# suggestions on how to approach batch process csv to web form app

Tags: php, forms, csv, automation

I am faced with challenge of taking a csv excel file of ups tracking numbers that i receive weekly, about 10 thousand. Batch process these numbers one by one into a web form and submit. Then need each result, which come back as xml, to be inserted into a mysql database for storage. Im wondering if there are any suggestions on how i should approach this. Automation is the goal. Was thinking when csv updates the process is handled. Using mysql and php. Im open to approaches especially if its a straight one. Thanks for your help.
Is mailparsing an option? Triggers?i seem to be having most problem figuring out the batch to web form process.

Comment: [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place to ask this as it's theory rather than practice. You can always come here if you get stuck implementing it!

Answer (score 0):

You normally solve that with basic math first:

```
10 000 tracking numbers
25 tracking numbers per form submissing take 1 minute (just guessed)
```

Results in:

```
400 minutes duration / 400 requests per week
Minutes per week: 70 560
Ca. one request per each 2,94 hours
```

Wihtout stressing any server you should be able to process these 10 000 tracking numbers in one week with enough room for growth.

First import the CSV file into a database table so you can easily fetch 25 entries from it and later on store the status into each of the lines.

As the tracking codes are unique (are they? probably at least per year or decade or something find out) you can easily keep track which numbers have not been checked yet.

For the web form you need to write yourself some function that is doing the HTML request posting the numbers to UPS and retrieving the result. You could also contact UPS if they offer some API, those are most often easier to operate with than with web-forms and site which change with the next re-design.